# My Dynamic Programming program is surprisingly adding numbers instead of solution

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

In the book "Introduction to Algorithms", I am trying to implement a Dynamic Programming problem which is known as "rod-cutting-program". Here I have an array defining the price of rods of variable lengths. So, array {1, 4} defines that, price of a rod with length 1 inch is 1$, and the price of a rod with length 4 is 4$ as well. I am given an input which is a length of a given rod. My goal is to cut the rod into multiple pieces so that the length of each piece remains integer and the total price of the pieces is maximized.

Here is my program

```
print("Input Length Prices: ")
p = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

def cut_rod(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    q = -1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        q = max(q, p[i-1] + cut_rod(n-1))

    return q

print("Input Length to Cut: ")
print(cut_rod(int(input())))
```

Here are my Input and Output.

**Input**

```
1 4
2
```

**Output**

```
5 (This is the sum of 1 and 4)
```

**Expected Output**

```
4
```

So instead of the maximized total price, it is giving the sum of all prices of lengths. I have tried several other inputs too. In all cases, it is giving the sum. It's very strange.

Edit: Rod can be kept uncut too.

Comment: Seems like the expected output should be 2, since the length of the rod is only 2.

Comment: @user3386109 No

Comment: Because the price of a length 2 rod is 4$. so 4 is the correct output. Rod can remain uncut. @user3386109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your program:

#1) You need `cut_rod(n-i)` rather than `cut_rod(n-1)` in your recursive call.  Once you remove a piece of length `i`, you have `p-i` remaining.

#2) You are repeatedly calling `cut_rod` recursively, and for large values of `n`, you are making `O(n*n)` recursive calls .  The point of dynamic programming is that you calculate the value for smaller results, and then **cache them** rather than recalculate them every time you need them.

Fortunately, Python makes this easy.  Just annotate your code with `@functools.lru_cache(None)`

=== Correction ===

I wrote above that this code without cacheing was `O(n*n)`.  This is actually exponential or worse.  The naive recursive implementation of Fibonacci numbers is exponential, and that only makes two recursive calls for each argument `n` greater than 2; this program makes `n - 1`.

Comment: Not sure the functools decorator is the best thing to use from a pedagogical standpoint. Either a bottom-up approach or handling the memoization explicitly would be better imho.

Comment: Sorry I typed n-i in the actual program. It's a typing mistake here because I wrote on mobile. And I tried on short input just for testing with naive $O(n^2)$ approach. I didn't apply DP on it yet. Edit: I somehow change to n-1 in the real code too. thanks

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was useful and thanks for informing the decorator. I didn't know about that before and used dictionaries for memoization.

Comment: @Tassle I think, we can use it in programming contests while we are short on time. And when the function contains more than a parameter lru_cache would be super time saver

Comment: @Md.AshrafulIslam Sure, I was just saying it might be good to see it done "by hand" to learn how it is done. Of course you are free to use any tool you want :)